# Is there a Python tool or technique to figure what's stopping my script from exiting?

Tags: python, anaconda

For some reason my code stopped exiting when it hits an exit() statement. This is the output I see on the screen:

```
Closing connections to test equipment.
motion device connection closed.
sampling device connection closed.
signal generator connection closed.
```

The code called to produce the output is this:

```
CloseEquipmentAndExit(equipment = [motion_device, sampling_device, gen], test_config = _test_settings, timestamps = script_timestamps)
```

Which calls this function:

```
def CloseEquipmentAndExit(equipment: list, test_config: dict, timestamps = None):
    sys.stdout.write('Closing connections to test equipment.\r\n')
    for item in equipment:
        try:
            if type(item) == motion_device:
                item.Move(test_config['Robot']['park'])
            item.Close()
            sys.stdout.write(f'{item.NAME} connection closed.\r\n')
            if not timestamps is None: timestamps.add(f"{item.NAME} Robot Close")
        except:
            pass
    exit()
```

From the output on the screen I should be stuck at the exit() statement, but my console hangs to the point of where Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break don't even get me back to the prompt. Is there any way for me figure out why my script isn't exiting?

Comment: Do you have a another bare `expect` statement somewhere that is catching and suppressing the `SystemExit` exception raised by `exit()`? This would also catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception raised by the default handler for `SIGINT` (generated by `Ctrl-C`), explaining why those don't terminate your script either.

Comment: This is one of the reasons you **don't use bare `except`**.

Comment: @chepner I do not have a try/except around that CloseEquipmentAndExit() function call. It is literally the last line of code in my script with zero statements afterward.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. How did you run the script? Are you sure there is a shell that can provide a new prompt?

Comment: @chepner I am running the script in a console window and I am able to run the script again in a new console window while the first one is locked up. A minimal reproducible example would be pretty difficult in this case as the motion device, sampling device, and signal generator mentioned in my output are classes with driver code beneath them. I'm not sure what I could post to StackOverflow that's less than 12 files long. Are there no tools in Python to determine what it is waiting for before it completes the exit()?

Comment: I'm asserting that the script *has* completed the `exit`, and that your console window simply isn't running *anything* any more. That's why I asked exactly how you are starting the script. (Are you typing `python myscript.py` at a shell prompt, or are you double-clicking on a file, or are you selecting a "Run" menu command in some IDE, or...)

Comment: @chepner I am typing `python myscript.py` at a command line.

Comment: More specifically, I'm using an Anaconda prompt. Maybe that is important here? I probably should have included Anaconda as a tag.